# p5.js:63704 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

So I wanna make a selector and when you hit the button called submit it would change the color of the "raindrops". Unfortunately I've been getting this error:

```
p5.js:63704 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefinedat at
_main.default.Element.eventPrependedFxn (p5.js:63704)
```

The code:

```js
// colors
let colorful = ["#1e68d6","#8c41db","#f274ec","#cf364d","#49c9c5","#4ac742","#dbc029","#de972c"];
let colorful2 = ["#7CB9E8","#FC8EAC","#FC6C85","#FF9999","#FFD1DC","#FFB7C5","#E75480","F2DBE7"," #C32148","#00308F","#D8BFD8","#DDA0DD","#DDA0DD","#9932CC","#4B0082","#E0B0FF","#9A4EAE","#9400D3","#8A2BE2","#FF8C00","#E26310","#F5761A","#ED9121","#FBCEB1","#F0F8FF","#FFD700","#F0E68C","#FFC72C","#FEBE10","#fff9d7","#0066b2","#C60C30","#A52A2A","#660000","#FBCEB1","#fd5c63","#97233F","#A91101","#5072A7","#6699CC","#002244","#7B68EE","#367588","#018749","#006A4E","#ACE1AF","#008B8B","#A9BA9D","#568203","#1B4D3E","#1F305E"];
let blacknwhite = 255;
let blues = ["#7CB9E8","#00308F","#F0F8FF","#0066b2","#5072A7","#6699CC","#002244","#7B68EE","#367588","#1F305E"];
let greens = ["#018749","#006A4E","#ACE1AF","#008B8B","#A9BA9D","#568203","#1B4D3E",];
let reds = ["#C60C30","#A52A2A","#660000","#FBCEB1","#fd5c63","#97233F","#A91101"];
let yellows = ["#FFD700","#F0E68C","#FFC72C","#FEBE10","#fff9d7"];//"#FFFF00"]; 
let oranges = ["#FF8C00","#E26310","#F5761A","#ED9121","#FBCEB1"];
let purples = ["#D8BFD8","#DDA0DD","#DDA0DD","#9932CC","#4B0082","#E0B0FF","#9A4EAE","#9400D3","#8A2BE2"];
let pinks = ["#FC8EAC","#FC6C85","#FF9999","#FFD1DC","#FFB7C5","#E75480","F2DBE7"," #C32148"];
let strawberry_ice_cream  = ["#5997ac","#a1cbdd","#eeede7","#f7aec2","#af5166"];
let the_mist = ["#c4d0d9","#d1d9dc","#dde2e3","#9d9c9a","#72747a"];
let greentea = ["#766e3f","#a69e70","#b6b9a3","#dbdfd9","#eeefea"];
let chocolate_carrot = ["#e6e8ea","#e7dcc8","#a5694b","#582719","#1b0d13"];
let the_dance = ["#d73d6c","#d57276","#d6c2bc","#c0cccc","#65b2c6"];
let advanture_time = ["#727072","#e6cfbf","#ae7862", "#b18e2c","#2b3120"];
let drops = []; // List of all the drops
let howmany = 100; // The amount of the raindrops
let thecolor = blues; 
//general params
let x1 = 1;
let x2 = 799;
let y1 = -300;
let y2 = -400;
let s1 = 1;
let s2 = 5;
let g1 = 0.1;
let g2 = 0.3;
///////THE CLASSES//////////
class raindrop {
    constructor(shape,color) {
    this.shape = shape;
    if(this.shape == "line"){
        this.raindrop = new line_raindrop(color);
    } else if(this.shape == "circle") {
        this.raindrop = new circle_raindrop(color);
    } else if(this.shape == "elipse") {
        this.raindrop = new elipse_raindrop(color);
    } else if(this.shape == "ractangle") {
        this.raindrop = new ractangle_raindrop(color);
    } else if(this.shape == "square"){
        this.raindrop = new square_raindrop(color);
    }
    }
    fall() {this.raindrop.fall();}
    show() {this.raindrop.show();}
}//line params
let l1 = 20;
let l2 = 250;
let w1 = 10;
let w2 = 100;
class line_raindrop {
    constructor(colors) {
        this.x = random(x1,x2); // the starting position 
        this.y = random(y1,y2); //      for the raindrop
        this.s = random(s1,s2); // speed
        this.c = random(colors); // color
        this.tempcolor = colors; // tempcolor
        this.g = random(g1,g2);
        this.l = random(l1,l2);
        this.w = random(w1,w2);
    }
    fall() {
        this.y = this.y + this.s;
        this.s = this.s + this.g;
        if(this.y > height) {
            this.x = random(x1,x2); // the starting position 
            this.y = random(y1,y2); //      for the raindrop
            this.s = random(s1,s2); // speed
            this.c = random(this.tempcolor); // tempcolor
            this.g = random(g1,g2);
            this.l = random(l1,l2);
            this.w = random(w1,w2);
        }
    }
    show(){
        strokeWeight(this.w);
        stroke(this.c)
        line(this.x,this.y,this.x,this.y + this.l);
    }
}
class select {
    constructor() {
        this.sel = createSelect();
        this.sel.position(0,400);
        this.sel.option("blues");
        this.sel.option("colorful");
        this.sel.option("blacknwhite");
        this.sel.selected("blues");
        this.sel.style('background-color',"#76B3FA");
        this.sel.style('background-color',"#76B3FA");
        this.sel.style('border-radius',"50px");
        this.sel.style("border","none");
        //this.sel.style("padding","10px 30px");
        this.sel.style("color", "#fff");
        this.sel.style("text-decoration", "none");       
        this.sel.style("font-size", "20px")
        //this.sel.style("margin", "0 15px");
        this.color = this.sel.value();
    }
} 
class submitbtn {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
        this.button = createButton("submit");
        this.button.position(100,400);
        this.button.style('background-color',"#76B3FA");
        this.button.style('background-color',"#76B3FA");
        this.button.style('border-radius',"50px");
        this.button.style("border","none");
        //this.button.style("padding","10px 30px");
        this.button.style("color", "#fff");
        this.button.style("text-decoration", "none");       
        this.button.style("font-size", "20px")
        //this.button.style("margin", "0 15px");
        this.button.mousePressed(this.a);
    }

}   
function setup() {
    createCanvas(800,500);
    // creating the drops
    for(var i = 0; i <= howmany-1; i++ ) {
      drops[i] = new raindrop("line",blues); 
    }//the DOM stuff
    let colorSelector = new select();
    let color = colorSelector.color;
    let submitButton = new submitbtn(submit(color));
}

function submit(color){
  if(color == "colorful"){
      for(var i = 0; i <= howmany-1; i++ ) {
          drops[i] = new raindrop("line",colorful); 
      }
  } else if(color == "blues") {
      for(var i = 0; i <= howmany-1; i++ ) {
          drops[i] = new raindrop("line",blues); 
      }
  }   else if(color == "blacknwhite") {
      for(var i = 0; i <= howmany-1; i++ ) {
          drops[i] = new raindrop("line",blacknwhite); 
      }
  }
}

  function draw() {
    background(61); 
    //makeing them do stuff
    for(var i = 0; i <= howmany-1; i++ ) {
      drops[i].show();
      drops[i].fall();
    }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Raindrop</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
</head>   
<body>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you'd like to see the error as well than you have to open the console of stackoverflow and the same error will apear there.
I tried to solve the problem by re nameing the variables that didn't work I tried to
do declare the submit function in the constructor but it did not work as well
on github you can examine my code in a way that is "more cleaned up" on the setup branch you will find all the files and the directories to this "project"
The github link to the setup branch: https://github.com/ytinoooon/js_rain/tree/setup

Comment: Have you used console.trace()?

Comment: Here is the console.trace():
submit @ sketch.js:31
setup @ sketch.js:14
_setup @ p5.js:62985
_start @ p5.js:62908
p5 @ p5.js:63261
_globalInit @ p5.js:62189
Promise.then (async)  
280.../core/main @ p5.js:62214
o @ p5.js:34
(anonymous) @ p5.js:38
267../accessibility/color_namer @ p5.js:54831
o @ p5.js:34
r @ p5.js:51
(anonymous) @ p5.js:55
(anonymous) @ p5.js:18
(anonymous) @ p5.js:20

Answer (score 1):

Your `submitbtn` class expects its parameter to be a callback function, but when you instantiate the `submitbtn` function in `setup()` you are calling the function `submit(color)` and passing the return value to the `submitbtn` constructor:

```js
// This invokes submit(color) immediately and passes undefined to 
// the submitbtn constructor
let submitButton = new submitbtn(submit(color));
```

You should be using a lambda function:

```js
// Note that you also need to reference colorSelector.color directly
// in the lambda function, as opposed to a local variable declared
// outside of the lambda.
let submitButton = new submitbtn(() => submit(colorSelector.color));
```

In order to make this work I also had to make the `select` class have a [property getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for `color` so that it actually reflects the value the user has selected instead of the default value.

```js
// colors
let colorful = ["#1e68d6", "#8c41db", "#f274ec", "#cf364d", "#49c9c5", "#4ac742", "#dbc029", "#de972c"];
let colorful2 = ["#7CB9E8", "#FC8EAC", "#FC6C85", "#FF9999", "#FFD1DC", "#FFB7C5", "#E75480", "F2DBE7", " #C32148", "#00308F", "#D8BFD8", "#DDA0DD", "#DDA0DD", "#9932CC", "#4B0082", "#E0B0FF", "#9A4EAE", "#9400D3", "#8A2BE2", "#FF8C00", "#E26310", "#F5761A", "#ED9121", "#FBCEB1", "#F0F8FF", "#FFD700", "#F0E68C", "#FFC72C", "#FEBE10", "#fff9d7", "#0066b2", "#C60C30", "#A52A2A", "#660000", "#FBCEB1", "#fd5c63", "#97233F", "#A91101", "#5072A7", "#6699CC", "#002244", "#7B68EE", "#367588", "#018749", "#006A4E", "#ACE1AF", "#008B8B", "#A9BA9D", "#568203", "#1B4D3E", "#1F305E"];
let blacknwhite = 255;
let blues = ["#7CB9E8", "#00308F", "#F0F8FF", "#0066b2", "#5072A7", "#6699CC", "#002244", "#7B68EE", "#367588", "#1F305E"];
let greens = ["#018749", "#006A4E", "#ACE1AF", "#008B8B", "#A9BA9D", "#568203", "#1B4D3E", ];
let reds = ["#C60C30", "#A52A2A", "#660000", "#FBCEB1", "#fd5c63", "#97233F", "#A91101"];
let yellows = ["#FFD700", "#F0E68C", "#FFC72C", "#FEBE10", "#fff9d7"]; //"#FFFF00"]; 
let oranges = ["#FF8C00", "#E26310", "#F5761A", "#ED9121", "#FBCEB1"];
let purples = ["#D8BFD8", "#DDA0DD", "#DDA0DD", "#9932CC", "#4B0082", "#E0B0FF", "#9A4EAE", "#9400D3", "#8A2BE2"];
let pinks = ["#FC8EAC", "#FC6C85", "#FF9999", "#FFD1DC", "#FFB7C5", "#E75480", "F2DBE7", " #C32148"];
let strawberry_ice_cream = ["#5997ac", "#a1cbdd", "#eeede7", "#f7aec2", "#af5166"];
let the_mist = ["#c4d0d9", "#d1d9dc", "#dde2e3", "#9d9c9a", "#72747a"];
let greentea = ["#766e3f", "#a69e70", "#b6b9a3", "#dbdfd9", "#eeefea"];
let chocolate_carrot = ["#e6e8ea", "#e7dcc8", "#a5694b", "#582719", "#1b0d13"];
let the_dance = ["#d73d6c", "#d57276", "#d6c2bc", "#c0cccc", "#65b2c6"];
let advanture_time = ["#727072", "#e6cfbf", "#ae7862", "#b18e2c", "#2b3120"];
let drops = []; // List of all the drops
let howmany = 100; // The amount of the raindrops
let thecolor = blues;
//general params
let x1 = 1;
let x2 = 799;
let y1 = -300;
let y2 = -400;
let s1 = 1;
let s2 = 5;
let g1 = 0.1;
let g2 = 0.3;
///////THE CLASSES//////////
class raindrop {
  constructor(shape, color) {
    this.shape = shape;
    if (this.shape == "line") {
      this.raindrop = new line_raindrop(color);
    } else if (this.shape == "circle") {
      this.raindrop = new circle_raindrop(color);
    } else if (this.shape == "elipse") {
      this.raindrop = new elipse_raindrop(color);
    } else if (this.shape == "ractangle") {
      this.raindrop = new ractangle_raindrop(color);
    } else if (this.shape == "square") {
      this.raindrop = new square_raindrop(color);
    }
  }
  fall() {
    this.raindrop.fall();
  }
  show() {
    this.raindrop.show();
  }
} //line params
let l1 = 20;
let l2 = 250;
let w1 = 10;
let w2 = 100;
class line_raindrop {
  constructor(colors) {
    this.x = random(x1, x2); // the starting position 
    this.y = random(y1, y2); //      for the raindrop
    this.s = random(s1, s2); // speed
    this.c = random(colors); // color
    this.tempcolor = colors; // tempcolor
    this.g = random(g1, g2);
    this.l = random(l1, l2);
    this.w = random(w1, w2);
  }
  fall() {
    this.y = this.y + this.s;
    this.s = this.s + this.g;
    if (this.y > height) {
      this.x = random(x1, x2); // the starting position 
      this.y = random(y1, y2); //      for the raindrop
      this.s = random(s1, s2); // speed
      this.c = random(this.tempcolor); // tempcolor
      this.g = random(g1, g2);
      this.l = random(l1, l2);
      this.w = random(w1, w2);
    }
  }
  show() {
    strokeWeight(this.w);
    stroke(this.c)
    line(this.x, this.y, this.x, this.y + this.l);
  }
}
class select {
  get color() {
    return this.sel.value();
  }

  constructor() {
    this.sel = createSelect();
    this.sel.position(0, height - 40);
    this.sel.option("blues");
    this.sel.option("colorful");
    this.sel.option("blacknwhite");
    this.sel.selected("blues");
    this.sel.style('background-color', "#76B3FA");
    this.sel.style('background-color', "#76B3FA");
    this.sel.style('border-radius', "50px");
    this.sel.style("border", "none");
    //this.sel.style("padding","10px 30px");
    this.sel.style("color", "#fff");
    this.sel.style("text-decoration", "none");
    this.sel.style("font-size", "20px")
    //this.sel.style("margin", "0 15px");
  }
}
class submitbtn {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
    this.button = createButton("submit");
    this.button.position(100, height - 40);
    this.button.style('background-color', "#76B3FA");
    this.button.style('background-color', "#76B3FA");
    this.button.style('border-radius', "50px");
    this.button.style("border", "none");
    //this.button.style("padding","10px 30px");
    this.button.style("color", "#fff");
    this.button.style("text-decoration", "none");
    this.button.style("font-size", "20px")
    //this.button.style("margin", "0 15px");
    this.button.mousePressed(this.a);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  // creating the drops
  for (var i = 0; i <= howmany - 1; i++) {
    drops[i] = new raindrop("line", blues);
  } //the DOM stuff
  let colorSelector = new select();
  let submitButton = new submitbtn(() => submit(colorSelector.color));
}

function submit(color) {
  console.log(color);
  if (color == "colorful") {
    for (var i = 0; i <= howmany - 1; i++) {
      drops[i] = new raindrop("line", colorful);
    }
  } else if (color == "blues") {
    for (var i = 0; i <= howmany - 1; i++) {
      drops[i] = new raindrop("line", blues);
    }
  } else if (color == "blacknwhite") {
    for (var i = 0; i <= howmany - 1; i++) {
      drops[i] = new raindrop("line", blacknwhite);
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(61);
  //makeing them do stuff
  for (var i = 0; i <= howmany - 1; i++) {
    drops[i].show();
    drops[i].fall();
  }

}
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```